# Error: accessing elements in char array initializer not working with char

Tags: c, char

I am new to C.
I just want to know why initializing the array of int with int is working and why initializing an array of char with char is not working. Or **am I wrong thinking that "1" is a char?**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     int incoming_message_test[2] = {1, 2}; // why does this work?
     char incoming_message[2] = {"1", "2"}; // why does this not work?
   
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"1"` is not a `char`, it's an array of two `char`s.

Comment: How do you know it does not work? You should include the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was a bit deeper than I first saw.

The first works because `char` is an integer type, and this code is perfectly valid:

```
int x = 42;
char c = x;
```

However, string literals cannot be converted that way. Instead of `"1"`, use `'1'`.

Answer (score 3):

You must change `"1", "2"` with `'1', '2'`

Answer (score 2):

In C:

1. `'c'` is a char
2. `"c"` is a string, meaning an array of N+1 chars. In this case char 'c' followed by string terminator `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

In C, a character literal contains one character that is surrounded with a single quotation ( ').

So instead of `"1", "2"`, use `'1', '2'`.

Answer (score 1):

> Or am I wrong thinking that "1" is a char ?

Yes.

For single characters, use single quotes.

So, define you array like so:

```
char incoming_message[2] = {'1', '2'};
```

Single-quote character literals have the type `char`, while double-quote string literals have the type `char *` (a pointer (address) to a char).